# Reference a worksheet from its name in a cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, reference, excel-2003

I am trying to find out how to make a reference that is defined by a cell value using VBA.

I have a form that inputs the name and location of a workbook into a cell (eg A1).  I then want my VBA code to take the value of this cell as a reference to the location of that file.

Instead of the reference being "f:test/file.xls" I would like it to be 'f:test/filedata.xls sheet1 A1' (clearly not a filepath but hopefully you get the idea).

This will allow me to build a set of interconnected workbooks that can be stored in different places and have different names without hard coding the locations every time (userform to input locations into the cells is used).

i am not sure if this is possible, and I certainly can't see anything like it yet.  Here's hoping!

Cheers

Comment: click here for [various ways to get data out of workbooks](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/various-ways-to-pull-data-from-another-workbook-closedopened/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are seeking to achieve, so I am not going to attempt to answer your question explicitly.  Instead, hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.

Below is a snippet of code that I have that references a cell on a spreadsheet and uses that cell as the file path to be combined with an adjacent cell that contains a file name.  They are then merged together and used to open that workbook.

I had to chop out a bunch of code from what I began with to make this example a lot more clear so I have not tested this as is.  However, I hope it serves a good launching point for what you are trying to achieve.

```
Private Sub OpenWBs(iCell)

Dim FilePath As String
Dim iCell As String

'refers to file path in cell A1
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

'refers to name of the workbook in cell A2
iCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value


If Not IsEmpty(iCell) Then 'checks for empty value, if found exits, if not opens workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath & iCell & ".xls", ReadOnly:=True
Else
    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Good luck!